# My phone says that its unable to connect to some apps

Tags: google-play-store, wi-fi, samsung, youtube

I have an Samsung J5 (2016) and since the afternoon I cant connect to whatsapp playstore youtube ebay and some other apps, the odd here is that it shows on the top that is connected and I can use apps like UC browser,Instagram and Google Chrome. I tried several option like clearing the cache deleting any antivirus app restarting it and changing the date and time, Nothing worked. After that i realized that worked perfectly on my friends house.
Please help me!

Comment: Might be a network issue? Can you please elaborate on the error if one is provided?